# 5.5 mo old female in heat. Male not interested. Should they still be separated?

Tags: cats

I have 2 5.5 month old kittens. Female is in heat and male (her brother) has absolutely no interest in her. Should I still separate them?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the risk is too high.

If you're lucky, the male one isn't sexually mature enough. If you're unlucky, he will show interest *very soon* and they'll mate. Don't think for a second that they won't mate just because they are brother and sister. Animals don't have moral thinking and follow their instincts. If a male finds a female in heat, he *will* mate with her, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Males usually mature later than females and since he is her brother there's a chance he won't be interested in her during this heat cycle as he's probably still not mature enough. However, males on average reach sexual maturity at 6 months so at 5.5 months I'd be really cautious cause there's still a chance he could develop interest. So I would separate them when you're not at home so you don't take the risk at all. But if by separating them you mean one has limited space and freedom cause say you put him in one room, then I'd personally let them be together and have full freedom BUT only when you're home and able to keep a close eye on them. If at any point he starts to harass her or especially if he tries to grab her by the neck, then its definitely time to separate and keep them separate until her heat is over with.

But it all depends on the level of risk you want to take. But the female is definitely too young to be ready for kittens and especially if you can't support any kittens right now, then it might be best to take the overly cautious route and just keep them separate until her current heat cycle is over with (as a side note, I tend to be overly cautious with my one intact cat and wait a couple days after she stopped showing symptoms of being in heat before I treat her as if her heat cycle is over with). Alternatively, if you don't want to watch them constantly, you can keep them separate but then let them be together for limited periods to interact or have full range of the house (when you have time to watch them closely and intervene that is).